# How can I load and run 2 models correctly？

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to load a keras model and 2 tf models and run them sequentially in a piece of code.However it doesn't work.How can I use them correctly?

Environment:Python-3.5,Tensorflow-1.14.0

Here is my code framework

```
load keras_model
load tf_model_1
load tf_model_2
predict using keras_model
predict using tf_model_1
predict using tf_model_2
```

The details about load and use tf_model

```py
g1 = tf.Graph()
sess_1 = tf.Session(graph=g1, config=get_config())


with sess_1.as_default():
    with sess_1.graph.as_default():
        print(tf.get_default_graph())
        output = build_model()
        init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
            'model1.ckpt',
            slim.get_model_variables(),
            ignore_missing_vars=True)
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess_1.run(init_op)
        init_fn(sess_1)
###########################
g2 = tf.Graph()
sess_2= tf.Session(graph=g2, config=get_config())


with sess_2.as_default():
    with sess_2.graph.as_default():
        print(tf.get_default_graph())
        output = build_model()
        init_fn = slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
            'model2.ckpt',
            slim.get_model_variables(),
            ignore_missing_vars=True)
        init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess_2.run(init_op)
        init_fn(sess_2)
```

when using tf_model

```py
with sess_1.as_default():
    with sess_1.graph.as_default():
        out = sess_1.run(
            [output], feed_dict={inputs: x})
```

The 3 model can all work correctly independently, but when I tried to combine in my order,it reports error when running tf_model_1:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I've already tried combining them with this sequence:

```
1.load keras_model
2.load tf_model_1
3.load tf_model_2
4.predict using keras_model
5.predict using tf_model_2
6.predict using tf_model_1
```

It can run till the step 6 and throw an error。So I doubt it is the problem with 2 different tensorflow graph.I joined this line when loading and runing tf_model

```py
print(tf.get_default_graph())
```

I got the output

```
loading tf_model_1:
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7fca53563550>
loading tf_model_2:
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7fca53559ba8>
runnng tf_model_1:
<tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7fca53563550>
```

It seems that it has set the correct tf graph when running the corresponding model,which makes me very confused.
Also without the second tf_model,I connected the keras model and one tf model.It works.

```
1.load keras_model
2.load tf_model_1

3.predict using keras_model
4.predict using tf_model_1
```

How can I use them correctly?